# Azure DevOps "ant not found"

Tags: azure-devops, ant

I have self-hosted Windows agent with pre-placed Ant and it is placed under C:\Program Files\ant\ however, when I try to use Ant task:

```
    - task: Ant@1
      inputs:
        buildFile: 'buildFiles\build.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: false
        antHomeDirectory: 'C:\Program Files\ant\'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
```

I get error message "Unable to locate executable file: 'ant'" even though the file is there under 'C:\Program Files\ant\bin'. How do I need to define the path in order for the executable to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I added `ANT_HOME` as the Windows environment variable and point it to my Ant folder in the self-hosted Windows agent.

[image]

2. Update PATH variable, add `%ANT_HOME%\bin` in the self-hosted Windows agent.

[image]

3. Restart the agent and check the agent Capabilities in project settings- agent pools, I can see `ant` and `ANT_HOME`.

[image]

4. Run the task, it will find the ant.exe.

[image]

Comment: I cannot access the GUI of this server so I run one PS script to set the paths:
              SET ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\ant\
              SET PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin that way I can use ant via command line but the Task still brings the same error.

Comment: Hi @Kamsiinov, could you please use this line  `Get-ChildItem Env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize`  PowerShell script in your pipeline to check the `ANT_HOME` and `PATH` value?